# ASP.NET Identity Session Timeout

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-identity

I use ASP.NET Identity .. I want to set session timeout to unlimited or max value. I've tried something but it doesn't effect. Note: I use shared hosting.
Thank you.

```
//web.config
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<authentication mode="Forms" />
<sessionState timeout="500000" />
</system.web>

//asp.identiyt config 
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365),
        LoginPath = new PathString("/user/login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, int>
                (
                     validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromDays(365),
                     regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                     getUserIdCallback: (id) => (Int32.Parse(id.GetUserId()))
                )
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Note that Session and the identity login aren't necessarily the same thing. Also; trying to keep sessions "forever" is a really, really bad idea. And pretty much impossible.

Comment: okay. i want to one week for example for timeout?

Comment: When you login to, for example, YouTube, you say logged in until you explicitly logout.   I'm pretty sure some of the people asking variations on this question are asking how to configure their Identity provider to behave in that manner.

Answer (score 7):

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{            
    var sessionTimeout = 20; // 

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
    });
}
```

Comment: How does this meet the "unlimited or max value" requirement?

Comment: You can't set session time out to  unlimited but u can set timeout as per your requirment in web config

Comment: *"You can't set the session time out to unlimited"* **That** would have been valid and related information to include. What you posted was just another way to try what the OP was already trying, that wasn't doing what they wanted.

Comment: this is the best answer, at least as close as one can get to "unlimited". Specifically you set the ExpireTimeSpan to something like the following:

 ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(45) 

which will allow the cookie to be valid fro 45 days

Comment: Can we presume the line `var sessionTimeout = 20; //` was just left in by accident in this example?  It's not used in the code.